# SharePoint 2013 server local to domain

Tags: active-directory, installation

I installed Sp 2013 farm into a local machine e now I Installed Active Directory with domains controller. SP Central admin doesn't work now. Should I re install everything or is there any workaround?

Comment: hello B, Could you accept one of the answers here? Please also review your other 60 questions for which you did not accept any answers. If you need more assistance - comment or edit the post. If someone's answer helped, accept it and let other users know it is a good solution. Try not to leave questions unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

1st thing if you have standalone installation of SharePoint(using SQL experss) on server then it is not supported.

As this is single server install, i would disconnect the farm and then re run the config wizard and recreate the farm. this will save your time on installation part.

I would recommend you to setup your dev farm like this:
[Setting Up an Awesome SharePoint 2013 Dev Box on Windows Server 2012 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2014/02/27/setting-up-an-awesome-sharepoint-2013-dev-box-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx)

Comment: No . I have installed it as farm not as standalone.

Answer (score 0):

@hello B,  [Waqas Sarwar MCSE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mcse) is right.

If you installed Active Directory AFTER installing SharePoint Farm, you mess up all the permissions and database access, because AD users are not the same as the users you had before.

I am guessing it is a dev environment (since u installed DC on SP machine), so the easiest way would be to start from scratch:

1. Install the server
2. Install AD
3. Install SQL (you need FULL SQL for the Farm, not the SQL Express that comes with Standalone).
4. Check if you can open any database using SQL Management Studio.
5. Install SharePoint (first prerequisites, then SP itself)

Alternatively, you can try to fix your permissions on the environment you have now, but honestly it will take longer than setting up the new machine, it will be difficult, and messy, and you will be on your own as I've never found a guide for that.

Answer (score 0):

Run SharePoint configuration wizard > disconnect this server from your farm if you didn't select standalone installation at the beginning of the current installation > after SharePoint configuration wizard has been finished try to run it again and configure new farm with the new domain users account.

Answer (score 0):

At least a complete recreation of the farm from the config database up is required.

If you installed AD on this specific server, then your local accounts that you used to configure SharePoint are now completely gone.  There are no local computer accounts on a DC (unlike a member server).  Thus a complete recreation is required for the farm.

You 'could' remount the existing content databases provided you grant the new accounts the necessary permissions.